# Going through array and moving duplicate items to a separate array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, sorting

I have an array I want to look against a specific key value pair.

```
var myObj = [
     {"name" : "Kanye", "song" : "Jesus Walks"},
     {"name" : "Axel Ross", "song" : "Thunder Struck"},
     {"name" : "Kate Perry", "song" : "Superbass"},
     {"name" : "Kanye", "song" : "Fade"},
     {"name" : "Kanye", "song" : "Old Kanye"},
];
```

What I want to get is two arrays that look like this.

```
var cleanObj = [
     {"name" : "Kanye", "song" : "Jesus Walks"},
     {"name" : "Axel Ross", "song" : "Thunder Struck"},
     {"name" : "Kate Perry", "song" : "Superbass"},
];

var duplicateObj = [
     {"name" : "Kanye", "song" : "Jesus Walks"},
     {"name" : "Kanye", "song" : "Fade"},
     {"name" : "Kanye", "song" : "Old Kanye"},
];
```

Currently I have something that looks like this.

```
var duplicateObj = [];
var cleanObj = {};

$.map(myObj, function (obj) {
    var checkDuplicate = myObj.some(function (elem) {
        return elem.name == obj.name;
    });
    if (checkDuplicate) {
        var tempObj = {
            name: obj.name,
            song: obj.song
        }
        duplicateObj.push(tempObj);
    } else {
        var tempObj = {
            name: obj.name,
            song: obj.song
        }
        cleanObj.push(tempObj);
    }
});
```

The issue with this is that it will not move the first instance of the duplicate object. Only the ones it compares after.

Any idea how I can also move the first instance of a duplicated item?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do duplicates share the same name?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes they share same name, only name not song

Comment: But in your desired outcome arrays, `Kanye` entry is also there in the cleanObj, but you say you don't want to include the first occurrence of duplicate items.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj yes the first instance of the name should be in clean AND duplicateObj, currently as stated my code will only move the second instance to duplicateObj

Comment: Take a look at my Snipet, if you use .filter method, the solution is quite simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hash table and filter and group the names, then render duplicates.

```js
var data = [{ name: "Kanye", song: "Jesus Walks" }, { name: "Axel Ross", song: "Thunder Struck" }, { name: "Kate Perry", song: "Superbass" }, { name: "Kanye", song: "Fade" }, { name: "Kanye", song: "Old Kanye" }],
    groups = Object.create(null),
    singles = data.filter(function (o) {
        if (!groups[o.name]) {
            groups[o.name] = [o];
            return true;
        }
        groups[o.name].push(o);
    }),
    duplicates = Object.keys(groups).reduce(function (r, k) {
        return r.concat(groups[k].length > 1 ? groups[k] : []);
    }, []);

console.log(singles);
console.log(duplicates);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myObj = [
     {"name" : "Kanye", "song" : "Jesus Walks"},
     {"name" : "Axel Ross", "song" : "Thunder Struck"},
     {"name" : "Kate Perry", "song" : "Superbass"},
     {"name" : "Kanye", "song" : "Fade"},
     {"name" : "Kanye", "song" : "Old Kanye"},
];
var non_duplicate = [];
var duplicate = [];
var name_array = [];
var dup_names = [];

$.each(myObj, function(idx, obj) {
  if ($.inArray(obj.name, name_array) == -1){        
    name_array.push(obj.name);
    non_duplicate.push(obj);
  }
  else{
    dup_names.push(obj.name);
  }
});

dups = $.unique(dup_names);

$.each(dups, function(idx1, obj1) {
  $.each(myObj, function(idx2, obj2) {
    if (obj2.name == obj1){        
      duplicate.push(obj2);
    }
  });
});

console.log(non_duplicate);
console.log(duplicate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you miss one in duplicates, the first one,

Comment: This does not produce the output that is expected by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I would use reduce to iterate over the array and create an object that contains duplicate array and clean array.

using Array.some I can tell if the clean array already have this artist and push him to the duplicate array, else- push it to the clean array.

if this is the first time i'm inserting this artist to the duplicate array, I will also insert it's item that in the clean array

```js
var myObj = [
     {"name" : "Kanye", "song" : "Jesus Walks"},
     {"name" : "Axel Ross", "song" : "Thunder Struck"},
     {"name" : "Kate Perry", "song" : "Superbass"},
     {"name" : "Kanye", "song" : "Fade"},
     {"name" : "Kanye", "song" : "Old Kanye"},
];

var ans = myObj.reduce((prev,curr)=>{
  if (!prev.clean.some(item => item.name == curr.name)) {
    prev.clean.push(curr);
  }
  else {
    if (!prev.duplicate.some(item => item.name == curr.name)) {
      prev.duplicate.push(prev.clean.find(item => item.name == curr.name));
    }
    prev.duplicate.push(curr);
  }
  return prev;
},{duplicate:[], clean:[]})

let duplicate = ans.duplicate;
let clean = ans.clean;

console.log(duplicate);
console.log(clean);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property "filter" of Array prototype, hope this helps:

```js
var myObj = [
     {"name" : "Kanye", "song" : "Jesus Walks"},
     {"name" : "Axel Ross", "song" : "Thunder Struck"},
     {"name" : "Kate Perry", "song" : "Superbass"},
     {"name" : "Kanye", "song" : "Fade"},
     {"name" : "Kanye", "song" : "Old Kanye"},
];
var singles = [];
var duplicates = [];

function exists(valor, onlySingles) {
  var cont = 0;
  for (item in myObj) {
    if (valor.name === myObj[item].name){
      cont++;
    }
  }
  if (cont > 1)
    return onlySingles ? false : true;
  else
    return onlySingles ? true : false;
}

singles = myObj.filter(exists, true);
duplicates = myObj.filter(exists, false);


console.log("singles:=>");
console.log(singles);
console.log("duplicates:=>");
console.log(duplicates);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the number of times a `name` appears, as a criteria to segregate.

```js
var myObj = [{
    "name": "Kanye",
    "song": "Jesus Walks"
  },
  {
    "name": "Axel Ross",
    "song": "Thunder Struck"
  },
  {
    "name": "Kate Perry",
    "song": "Superbass"
  },
  {
    "name": "Kanye",
    "song": "Fade"
  },
  {
    "name": "Kanye",
    "song": "Old Kanye"
  },
];

var cleanObj = [],
  duplicateObj = [];
var mNameCount = {};

myObj.forEach(function(obj) {
  if (!mNameCount[obj.name]) {
    mNameCount[obj.name] = 0;
    cleanObj.push(obj);
  }
  mNameCount[obj.name]++;
});

myObj.forEach(function(obj) {
  if (mNameCount[obj.name] > 1) {
    duplicateObj.push(obj);
  }
});
console.log(cleanObj);
console.log(duplicateObj);
```